# Calling library functions in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, libraries

Case I: In some cases, I use the library name to call some set of function i.e, np.median(). 
Case II: And in some cases, I use the variable name and library name to call another set of function i.e, np.mean(heights) or heights.mean().
In case II, I am able to use both library name and variable name. In case I, only library name works.

My doubt is how to differentiate these tow sets of functions.
If I am wrong in anyway, please clear my thoughts.
(here i am referring to python language)

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you’re calling a method (function) of the library. Libraries are usually class instances or collections of functions within a module.

In the second example instead, you’re again calling a function from the module but in this case it returns a ndarray (a numpy list basically) which itself has some methods that can be called on it.

Comment: thank you. I need some more clarifications. How do you decide which one uses library name or variable name?

Comment: In one case you're using a method directly exposed by the library, in the other you're acting on an item that was generated by this library and that itself exposes some of these methods. You should look into Object Oriented Programming patterns, but generally speaking referring to official documentation is a good start. If you look at `np.mean` for instance you see that the first parameter is an `array_like`, which is to say it takes an input and that in the output has `ndarray`. Looking at `ndarray`, an object that has many methods which operate on or with the array in some fashion.